# How to shorten code using SQL Command

Tags: c#, sql, data-access-layer

**Here is my problem:**
I want to make my code short, and a friend of mine told me that I can use DAL.
But I don't know how to use DAL. I also tried to search internet. But It doesn't
give me some simple solution. I'm a newbie using DAL

**Note:** I know that my select command is very short but imagine that as an
extensive data.

**ASPX code**

```
<div>
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl1" Text="FirstName" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFName" runat="server" />
    </div>            
    <div>
        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl2" Text="MiddleName" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMName" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl3" Text="LastName" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLName" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl4" Text="Birthday" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtBday" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl5" Text="Address" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAdd" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**ASPX.cs code**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SelectCommand();
}

private void SelectCommand()
{
    SqlCommand sqlSelect = new SqlCommand();
    sqlSelect.Connection = conn;
    sqlSelect.CommandText = "select FirstName = @FirstName,MiddleName = @MiddleName,LastName = @LastName,BirthDate = @BirthDate, Address = @Address from User";
    sqlSelect.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    sqlSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFName.Text);
    sqlSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleName", txtFName.Text);
    sqlSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtFName.Text);
    sqlSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthDate", txtBday.Text);
    sqlSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAdd.Text);
    conn.Open();
    sqlSelect.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: [Start here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581776.aspx). This is a tutorial for creating Data Access Layer

Comment: hi @noobob I tried to read that but I really can't understand. =(

Comment: Please try to google it and find examples. The DAL is an architectural concern but the implementation may varies depending on the technology used. Find what suits you.

Answer (score 0):

Try separating your purposes into separate projects.

Try reading through http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design). I know wikipedia is very bland but may help give you some fundamental principles on OO design.

You can always use linq to sql or entity framework and remove a lot of redundant code however it will almost likely be slower than just writing it yourself.